# How to create a kubernetes service yaml file without --dry-run

Tags: kubernetes, service-node-port-range

It seems that `--dry-run` flag is not available for service.

```
kubectl create service --
--add-dir-header            --log-backtrace-at          --server                  
--alsologtostderr           --log-dir                   --skip-headers            
--as                        --log-file                  --skip-log-headers        
--as-group                  --log-file-max-size         --stderrthreshold         
--cache-dir                 --log-flush-frequency       --tls-server-name         
--certificate-authority     --logtostderr               --token                   
--client-certificate        --match-server-version      --user                    
--client-key                --namespace                 --username                
--cluster                   --password                  --v                       
--context                   --profile                   --vmodule                 
--insecure-skip-tls-verify  --profile-output            --warnings-as-errors      
--kubeconfig                --request-timeout
```

Is there a way to create a service yaml file without `--dry-run=client` option. I tried with the below command and getting an error.

```
kubectl create service ns-service nodeport --dry-run=client -o yaml >nodeport.yaml
Error: unknown flag: --dry-run
See 'kubectl create service --help' for usage.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.
**=================================================================**

**First Way:**- using `kubectl create service`

What wrong you are doing here is you are giving service name befor the service type in command that's why its failing.

correct way is

**Syntax :**

```
kubectl create service clusterip NAME [--tcp=<port>:<targetPort>] [--dry-run=server|client|none] [options]
```

**Example :**

```
kubectl create service nodeport ns-service --tcp=80:80 --dry-run=client -o yaml
```

**=================================================================**

**Second way:-**

Here you can use `kubectl expose` command to create a service file.

Let's assume you have a pod running with the name **nginx**. and you want to create a service for **nginx** pod.

then I will write below command to generate the service file.

Synatax:

```
kubectl expose [pod/deployment/replicaset] [name-of-pod/deployment/replicaset]  --port=80 --target-port=8000 --dry-run=client -o yaml
```

Example:

```
kubectl expose pod nginx  --port=80 --target-port=8000 --dry-run=client -o yaml
```

output:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    run: nginx
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```